# Reactive JWT authentication using Spring webflux

Tags: java, security, spring, jwt

Greeting to all senior devs here. I'm trying to create a project for my small business. There are not many tutorial on how to create Reactive JWT authentication with Spring webflux. So I'm a bit scared if I make any vulnerabilities. If you could help me review this project I would be grateful. So let's get started.

**Security configuration class.** I have two difference authentication manager. One for global authentication and one for JWT validation.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity(proxyTargetClass = true)
public class SpringSecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private ReactiveUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public ReactiveAuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        UserDetailsRepositoryReactiveAuthenticationManager authenticationManager =
                new UserDetailsRepositoryReactiveAuthenticationManager(userDetailsService);
        authenticationManager.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authenticationManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http,
                                                      JWTTokenService jwtTokenService) throws Exception {

        return http.csrf().disable()
                   .authorizeExchange()
                   .pathMatchers("/api/v1/user/signin", "/api/v1/user/signup")
                   .permitAll()
                   .anyExchange()
                   .authenticated()
                   .and()
                   .addFilterAt(bearerAuthenticationFilter(localAuthenticationManager(), jwtTokenService), SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION)
                   .build();
    }

    private AuthenticationWebFilter bearerAuthenticationFilter(ReactiveAuthenticationManager authManager, JWTTokenService jwtTokenService) {
        AuthenticationWebFilter bearerAuthenticationFilter = new AuthenticationWebFilter(authManager);
        bearerAuthenticationFilter.setServerAuthenticationConverter(new ServerHttpBearerAuthenticationConverter(jwtTokenService));

        return bearerAuthenticationFilter;
    }

    private ReactiveAuthenticationManager localAuthenticationManager() {
        return new ReactiveAuthenticationManager () {
            @Override
            public Mono<Authentication> authenticate(Authentication authentication) {
                return Mono.just(authentication)
                           .filter(Authentication::isAuthenticated)
                           .map(auth -> (String) auth.getPrincipal())
                           .flatMap(username -> userDetailsService.findByUsername(username))
                           .filter(UserDetails::isEnabled)
                           .map(user -> authentication)
                           .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new AccessDeniedException("Unauthorized user.")));
            }
        };
    }
}
```

**Server http bearer authentication converter class.** It responsible for converting any authenticated  request to JWT Token authentication.

```
public class ServerHttpBearerAuthenticationConverter implements ServerAuthenticationConverter {
    private static final String BEARER = "Bearer ";
    private static final Predicate<String> matchBearerLength = authValue -> authValue.length() > BEARER.length();
    private static final Function<String, Mono<String>> isolateBearerValue = authValue -> Mono.justOrEmpty(authValue.substring(BEARER.length()));

    private final JWTTokenService jwtTokenService;

    public ServerHttpBearerAuthenticationConverter(JWTTokenService jwtTokenService) {
        this.jwtTokenService = jwtTokenService;
    }

    public static Mono<String> extract(ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange) {
        return Mono.justOrEmpty(serverWebExchange.getRequest()
                   .getHeaders()
                   .getFirst(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION));
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Authentication> convert(ServerWebExchange exchange) {
        return Mono.justOrEmpty(exchange)
                   .flatMap(ServerHttpBearerAuthenticationConverter::extract)
                   .filter(matchBearerLength)
                   .flatMap(isolateBearerValue)
                   .flatMap(jwtTokenService::validateTokenAndGetUsername)
                   .map(username ->
                           new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, null, new ArrayList<>()));
    }
```

**JWT token service. For generate and validate JWT token.**

```
@Service
public class JWTTokenService {

    private final Algorithm hmac512;
    private final JWTVerifier verifier;

    private final int EXPIRATION_TIME = 900_000;
    private final String SECRET = "inject_from_env_later";

    public JWTTokenService() {
        this.hmac512 = Algorithm.HMAC512(SECRET);
        this.verifier = JWT.require(this.hmac512).build();
    }

    public String generateToken(final UserDetails userDetails) {
        return JWT.create()
                  .withSubject(userDetails.getUsername())
                  .withExpiresAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + EXPIRATION_TIME))
                  .sign(this.hmac512);
    }

    public Mono<String> validateTokenAndGetUsername(final String token) {
        try {
            return Mono.just(verifier.verify(token))
                       .map(Payload::getSubject);
        } catch (final JWTVerificationException verificationEx) {
            // log.logwarn("token invalid: {}", verificationEx.getMessage());
            return Mono.empty();
        }
    }
}
```

**UserController for signup and signin method.**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/user")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ReactiveUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private ReactiveAuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private JWTTokenService jwtTokenService;

    @PostMapping("/signup")
    public Mono<User> signupUser(@RequestBody RequestSignupUser request) {
        return userRepository.save(new User(UUID.randomUUID(),
                                            request.getUsername(),
                                            passwordEncoder.encode(request.getPassword())));
    }

    @PostMapping("/signin")
    public Mono<AuthenticationResponse> siginUser(@RequestBody RequestSigninUser request) {
        try {
            return authenticationManager.authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(request.getUsername(),
                                                            request.getPassword()))
                            .flatMap(authen -> userDetailsService.findByUsername(request.getUsername()))
                            .map(user -> new AuthenticationResponse(jwtTokenService.generateToken(user)));
        } catch (final BadCredentialsException ex) {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        }
    }
}
```

I have tested with PostMan several times and it works just fine I think?